# Whenever I start my app using `npm start` it brings me to the Ruby on Rails Homescreen instead of my index.html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I am new to software development, but I know how to use `React/Redux` very well, as well as `Ruby-On-Rails`. I am trying to have a React Frontend powered by a Rails backend. I understand conceptually how `Node.js` works, but not exactly the minutia. My app worked perfectly in the beginning stages before I committed any migrations, thus during testing I did not ever run `rails s.` Now, whenever I do, as soon as I run `npm start` it brings me to the rails homepage and nowhere in any of the code I've created. I've created apps before and never ran into this problem, and I know enough to surmise that the issue probably lies in the `packagae.json` file inside the src directory, but other than that I have no idea what to do and no errors to even google. I don't even know what files or code I should be showing... regardless, here is my packagae.json file as my `index.js` file

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "legend_of_cliches",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import masterReducer from './reducers/master_reducer';

//  Sets up Store and Debuggers
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(masterReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: is you rails running on port 3000, do you see rails page when you access localhost:3000?

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you!